# Performance of Calling a Function Multiple Times vs Assigning to a Local Variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

Just curious, say I have this Seeded Function `FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID` that returns the User_ID of the currently logged in user, and I have a custom package (below) that updates a bunch of tables (table dml and ddl at the end of the question).

One Procedure makes a single call to `FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID` and assigns it to a local variable, the other makes multiple calls to `FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID`:

```
create or replace package call_pkg_var is

    procedure call_once (p_trx_no number);
    procedure call_multi (p_trx_no number);

end call_pkg_var;
/

create or replace package body call_pkg_var is

    procedure call_once (p_trx_no number)
    is

        l_user_id   number := fnd_global.user_id;

    begin

        update table_a
        set    user_id = l_user_id
        where  trx_no =  p_trx_no;

        update table_b
        set    user_id = l_user_id
        where  trx_no =  p_trx_no;

        update table_c
        set    user_id = l_user_id
        where  trx_no =  p_trx_no;    

    end call_once;

    procedure call_multi (p_trx_no number)
    is
    begin

        update table_a
        set    user_id = FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID
        where  trx_no =  p_trx_no;

        update table_b
        set    user_id = FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID
        where  trx_no =  p_trx_no;

        update table_c
        set    user_id = FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID
        where  trx_no =  p_trx_no;

    end call_multi;

end call_pkg_var;
/
```

On Separate Sessions, I ran the Scripts below to update the table using `call_pkg_var.call_once`:

```
set timing on;
begin

  for i in 1 .. 10000 loop  
    call_pkg_var.call_once(i);    
  end loop;

  commit;

end;
```

and this one using `call_pkg_var.call_multi`:

```
set timing on;
begin

  for i in 1 .. 10000 loop  
    call_pkg_var.call_multi(i);    
  end loop;

  commit;

end;
```

Results:

```
Run#    call_pkg_var.call_once
------- -----------------------
1       00:00:02.248
2       00:00:02.100
3       00:00:02.101
4       00:00:02.069
5       00:00:02.136
6       00:00:02.113
------  -------------
Average 00:00:02.128


Run#    call_pkg_var.call_multi
------- -----------------------
1       00:00:02.051
2       00:00:02.047
3       00:00:02.054
4       00:00:02.071
5       00:00:02.054
6       00:00:02.051
------  -------------
Average 00:00:02.055
```

Does this somehow say that calling a function multiple times is better than just assigning it to a variable?
if not, what is the best approach to take?

**Table DML and DDLs**

```
create table table_a
(
  user_id number,
  trx_no  number
);  

create table table_b
(
  user_id number,
  trx_no  number
);  

create table table_c
(
  user_id number,
  trx_no  number
);  

insert into table_a (trx_no, user_id) values (1, null);
insert into table_b (trx_no, user_id) values (1, null);
insert into table_c (trx_no, user_id) values (1, null);
```

Comment: Call these procedures in a loop 10000 times and compare average times. Repeat this measure 3-5 times. Then please append results of this evaluation to the question.

Comment: i've added the loop and the ran the test 6 times. seems the multiple calls is still faster. thoughts? @krokodilko

Comment: You have deleted results of the first test from the question - as I remember, there were about 200ms vs 300ms (ms=milisecond) the difference was ~90ms for single call. The second test - 2 seconds 128 miliseconds vs. 2 seconds 55 miliseconds - a difference is: 88 miliseconds for 10000 cals. Yes, It's absolutely faster, about 8,8 microseconds (a few CPU cycles) per one call, this is very impresive achievement.

Comment: I don't know if you did this just as a test, but the current user in Oracle can be obtained in PL/SQL and SQL via "USER". Other than using USER, you can make a call to SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER'), or SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER'), or many other things. Check out SYS_CONTEXT at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions184.htm#SQLRF06117

Comment: Hi @BrianLeach `FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID` is an application specific package (in Oracle EBS), but i just used that concept sample to my question. so yes, it was only used as a test.

Comment: @krokodilko, agree that it isn't much of a deal breaker when it comes to performance. how about best practice? call once or call multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

i agree brian's point.Always try to use the oracle's in built functions to get the desired outputs.You can use sys_context for getting current  user and i'm not sure what other  method you are using.Try to avoid the switch  context between sql and pl/sql

Comment: There is no reason to think that package `FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID` returns anything related to anything retrievable via `SYS_CONTEXT`.  It could be an application-specific user ID that has nothing to do with the database user ID.

Comment: Hi @jayaprakash-nagarajan as Matthew stated, `FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID` is an application-specific function in Oracle EBS, but i just used that concept sample to my question. getting the user was not the focus of my question, rather, it was the performance between calling the function multiple times versus calling it once and assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably not known to most people here is that `FND_GLOBAL` is a package delivered by Oracle Corporation as part of their Oracle e-Business Suite.

If you review the source code for that package, you will see that `FND_GLOBAL` already caches the `USER_ID`, which is the e-BS user id not the Oracle Database user id, in a PL/SQL variable.  So, your "call once" and "call multi" are doing almost exactly the same amount of work.

I'd expect that the "call multi" is still doing a *little* more work -- and that you'd be able to detect that if you ran a lot of tests and evaluated the results statistically.

However, if you are on Oracle 12c, I am not sure in that release whether they removed the limitation that the PL/SQL optimizer could only inline calls to functions in the same program unit.  If you enable PL/SQL warnings, you should get warnings if any sort of inlining is going on.

For reference, here is how you do that:

```
alter session set plsql_warnings='enable:all';

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE...  << your package code >>

show errors;   -- Works in SQL*Plus, take your chances with other IDEs.
```

Comment: I'm on 11g, but i'm curious about the inlinings. can you edit and give a sample of those? thanks!